# Gremlin on Azure CosmosDB: how to project the related vertices' properties?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin

I use Microsoft.Azure.Graphs library to connect to a Cosmos DB instance and query the graph database.

I'm trying to optimize my Gremlin queries in order to only select those properties that I only require. However, I don't know how to choose which properties to select from edges and vertices.

Let's say we start from this query:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('user').
   project('user', 'edges', 'relatedVertices')
     .by()
     .by(bothE().fold())
     .by(both().fold())
```

This will return something along the lines of:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "<userId>",
        "type": "vertex",
        "label": "user",
        "properties": [
            // all vertex properties
        ]
    },
    "edges": [{
        "id": "<edgeId>",
        "type": "edge",
        "label": "<edgeName>",
        "inV": <relatedVertexId>,
        "inVLabel": "<relatedVertexLabel>",
        "outV": "<relatedVertexId>",
        "outVLabel": "<relatedVertexLabel>"
        "properties": [
            // edge properties, if any
        ]
    }],
    "relatedVertices": [{
        "id": "<vertexId>",
        "type": "vertex",
        "label": "<relatedVertexLabel>",
        "properties": [
            // all related vertex properties
        ]
    }]
}
```

Now let's say we only take a couple of properties from the root vertex which we named "User":

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('user').
   project('id', 'prop1', 'prop2', 'edges', 'relatedVertices')
     .by(id)
     .by('prop1')
     .by('prop2')
     .by(bothE().fold())
     .by(both().fold())
```

Which will make some progress for us and yield something along the lines of:

```
{
    "id": "<userId>",
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "edges": [{
        "id": "<edgeId>",
        "type": "edge",
        "label": "<edgeName>",
        "inV": <relatedVertexId>,
        "inVLabel": "<relatedVertexLabel>",
        "outV": "<relatedVertexId>",
        "outVLabel": "<relatedVertexLabel>"
        "properties": [
            // edge properties, if any
        ]
    }],
    "relatedVertices": [{
        "id": "<vertexId>",
        "type": "vertex",
        "label": "<relatedVertexLabel>",
        "properties": [
            // all related vertex properties
        ]
    }]
}
```

Now is it possible to do something similar to edges and related vertices? Say, something along the lines of:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('user').
   project('id', 'prop1', 'prop2', 'edges', 'relatedVertices')
     .by(id)
     .by('prop1')
     .by('prop2')
     .by(bothE().fold()
         .project('edgeId', 'edgeLabel', 'edgeInV', 'edgeOutV')
              .by(id)
              .by(label)
              .by(inV)
              .by(outV))
     .by(both().fold()
         .project('vertexId', 'someProp1', 'someProp2')
              .by(id)
              .by('someProp1')
              .by('someProp2'))
```

My aim is to get an output like this:

```
{
    "id": "<userId>",
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "edges": [{
        "edgeId": "<edgeId>",
        "edgeLabel": "<edgeName>",
        "edgeInV": <relatedVertexId>,
        "edgeOutV": "<relatedVertexId>"
    }],
    "relatedVertices": [{
        "vertexId": "<vertexId>",
        "someProp1": "someValue1",
        "someProp2": "someValue2"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   project('name','age','edges','relatedVertices').
......2>   by('name').
......3>   by('age').
......4>   by(bothE().
......5>      project('id','inV','outV').
......6>        by(id).
......7>        by(inV().id()).
......8>        by(outV().id()).
......9>      fold()).
.....10>   by(both().
.....11>      project('id','name').
.....12>        by(id).
.....13>        by('name').
.....14>      fold())
==>[name:marko,age:29,edges:[[id:9,inV:3,outV:1],[id:7,inV:2,outV:1],[id:8,inV:4,outV:1]],relatedVertices:[[id:3,name:lop],[id:2,name:vadas],[id:4,name:josh]]]
==>[name:vadas,age:27,edges:[[id:7,inV:2,outV:1]],relatedVertices:[[id:1,name:marko]]]
==>[name:josh,age:32,edges:[[id:10,inV:5,outV:4],[id:11,inV:3,outV:4],[id:8,inV:4,outV:1]],relatedVertices:[[id:5,name:ripple],[id:3,name:lop],[id:1,name:marko]]]
==>[name:peter,age:35,edges:[[id:12,inV:3,outV:6]],relatedVertices:[[id:3,name:lop]]]
```

Two points you should consider when writing Gremlin:

1. The output of the previous step feeds into the input of the following step and if you don't clearly see what's coming out of a particular step, then the steps that follow may not end up being right. In your example, in the first `by()` you added the `project()` after the `fold()` which was basically saying "Hey, Gremlin, project that `List` of edges for me." But in the `by()` modulators for `project()` you treated the input to project not as a `List` but as individual edges which likely led to an error. In Java, that error is: "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element". An error like that is a clue that somewhere in your Gremlin you are not properly following the outputs and inputs of your steps.
2. `fold()` takes all the elements in the stream of the traversal and converts them to a `List`. So where you had many objects, you will now have one after the `fold()`. To process them as a stream again, you would need to `unfold()` them for steps to operate on them individually. In this case, we just needed to move the `fold()` to the end of the statement after doing the sub-`project()` for each edge/vertex. But why do we need `fold()` at all? The answer is that the traversal passed to the `by()` modulator is not iterated completely by the step that it modifies (in this case `project()`). The step only calls `next()` to get the first element in the stream - this is by design. Therefore, in cases where you want the entire stream of a `by()` to be processed you must reduce the stream to a single object. You might do that with `fold()`, but other examples include `sum()`, `count()`, `mean()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your time. This was the solution, but unfortunately it fails somewhere deep in the call stack, causing a null reference exception. The failure is caused by that last `by(id)` when projecting related vertices' IDs. If I remove that `Id` and leave only `project('name').by('name')` then it works fine. I will try to connect to CosmosDB using the Gremlin.Net later and see if it happens with it too, or it's only a bug in Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.dll. Too bad Gremlin.Net can't connect to local CosmosDB emulator...

Comment: ... interestingly enough, doesn't crash when retrieving the edges' IDs!

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a CosmosDB thing -
`Gremlin.Net.Driver.Exceptions.ResponseException: ServerError: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  ExceptionType : NullReferenceException
  Source : Microsoft.Azure.Graphs
  HResult : 0x80004003
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.TraversalOperator.<NextAsync>d__11.MoveNext()`

Comment: One more update from me: If I specify `by(id())` instead of `by(id)` in the last step, it works fine! Thanks again!

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Can you provide the repro query that you ran which got the exception? In Stephen's example, I don't see a reference to `by(id())`, only `by(id)`,  but on the face of it sounds like a bug in CosmosDB Graph.

Comment: @OliverTowers sure thing, do you want me to post the minimal repro query here as a comment?

Comment: @OliverTowers here you go. This one works: `g.V().project("RelatedVertices").by(both().project("Id").by(id()).fold())` 
but this one does not: `g.V().project("RelatedVertices").by(both().project("Id").by(id).fold())` - causes `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Runtime.Operators.TraversalOperator.<ComputeNextRecordAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
`

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Thanks, I'll look into this.

Comment: @OliverTowers you're welcome. I've got my workaround for this particular case, but I believe the community would be grateful if you guys also update the local CosmosDB emulator after fixing this bug